# How to determine if an app is authorized to a fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

Forgive me if this has been asked before, but I was unable to find an answer to what seems a simple question.  I have an app that is authorized to a user & user's fan page via a process from a website I've constructed.  The process is this:

Visit Website --> authorize website to view list of fan pages --> Select Fan Page to install app to --> Authorize app to user account --> Authorize app to Fan Page

I've got all that working (a process, let me tell you), and everything functions as intended.  I'm working on an admin interface to manage the app which is not housed in the Canvas App location but on the website itself.  I haven't found a way to figure out if the app is installed or not.  It appears that the Graph API / FQL doesn't support this.

My two issues are:

- I have the user id & the fan page id but I can't figure out whether said fan page has my app authorized or not.  Depending on this answer will determine whether I show the "Install This App" panel or the Administration panel.
- I've read that the best method is to store the userid when the app is initially authorized, but after the app is authorized, the user is sent to the Fan Page's Wall and I can't figure out how to notify my iframe app.

Comment: Updated the title of this question to reflect the answer to help anyone else stuck on this particular hurdle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] I misunderstood your question and thought you had less implemented than you seem to have: If you have `manage_pages` permission for a user, you can get the Page access token for each of their pages, and access a list of apps currently installed as tabs on that page - the instructions are at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs 
[/edit]

Each request made to your app's 'page tab url' will include a signed_request parameter.
The method to decode it is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ - when your app is loaded on a page tab you'll get the 'page' parameter.

So:

1. The first time the tab provided by your app is loaded on a new page, you can detect the page ID from the signed request.
2. This callback will also tell you if the user currently looking at the page tab is an admin of that page (which can be useful for your own edit interface, if applicable)
3. If you haven't already got an interface where the app user tells you which pages they admin you can get a list of all the pages that user administers by accessing the 'accounts' property on their user object (`/me/accounts` in the Graph API) once you have the `manage_pages` permission

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  I was looking for Pages > Apps, forgetting the nomenclature that they become "tabs" on a fan page.

I have the manage_pages perm already, so I just have to retrieve the  token from the page in question (which I already know), and use that token to request /PAGE_ID/tabs which gives me a wealth of information including what I was after.  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

can you keep track of who has the app authorized in a database on your website?

i.e. call a script on your website server from your app that returns whether or not the user has authorized the app.

Comment: Yes, and that's actually what I'm going to achieve after the above answer.  Basically, my site uses Facebook Connect (which requires authorization) to retrieve the Facebook User's information as well as their pages (with the `manage_pages` permission).  From there, I can verify against a page whether or not they have installed my app using the above poster's answer.